# error when creating a new angular project after updating the cli version

Tags: angular

I had angular cli 6.* installed in my mac and I wanted to update this version to 8.*
after doing this the `ng new app` return an error.

Terminal :

```
...
CREATE timelines/e2e/src/app.po.ts (251 bytes)
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: timelines@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: jasmine-core@3.4.0
npm ERR! node_modules/jasmine-core
npm ERR!   dev jasmine-core@"~3.4.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer jasmine-core@">=3.5" from karma-jasmine-html-reporter@1.5.4
npm ERR! node_modules/karma-jasmine-html-reporter
npm ERR!   dev karma-jasmine-html-reporter@"^1.4.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /Users/tarek/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/tarek/.npm/_logs/2021-04-30T10_18_04_291Z-debug.log
Package install failed, see above.
```

I tried to delete everything related to Angular, npm, angular cli etc... and re install them but  errors still persist

package.json file :

```
{
  "name": "timelines",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.802.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.2.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.0",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  }
}
```

I could not create projects any more
please help

Comment: Try uninstalling `@angular/cli` globally and re-installing it. Also, going from 6 to 8 is not recommended. You should go one version at a time (6 to 7, then 7 to 8).

Comment: I have the some problem with angular 11, have you found a workaround?

Comment: I just had this problemm with angular 11.  So I removed 11 as `@latest` and installed `@~10` -- Same result.  I repeated the cycle and installed `@~9` and then `@~8`.  SAME problem every time.  I had no pre-installed Angular before thie evening, so I can't say it would be a migration _thing_ especiall when the problem is with `ng new`.  Hope someone figures out a workaround.

Comment: I have the same problem with angular 11, yesterday was working fine, today start to fail, so I can't create new projects, and because Iḿ making an angular trainng I need to make several projects.

Comment: Workaround: Create project with `ng new my-app --skip-install`, go to the app directory, remove all jasmine dependencies from package.json and run `npm install`.  You won't be able to run `npm test`, but the project will build and run.

Answer (score 1):

May be following steps would work:

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

OR

```
npm cache clean --force    
npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: Create a project with `ng new my-app --skip-install`, go to the app directory, remove all jasmine dependencies from `package.json` and run `npm install`. You won't be able to run npm test, but the project will build and run

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your `Node` version is incompatible. Try to update `Node` to the latest stable version, then install `@angular/cli` globally, and then try to create a new `Angular` project.